# Probability of an Event Occuring (Set Help)

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

The original question states (simplified): Event A occurs with the probability 0.22, event B with probability 0.30, and event C with probability 0.28. The probability of both A and B (*I stated this as* $A \cap B$) 0.11, both A and C ($A \cap C$) 0.14, and both B and C ($B \cap C$) with probability 0.10. The probability of all three occuring ($A \cap B \cap C$) is 0.06. What is the probability that:

1. None of these occur
2. 2 or more occur
3. Exactly one of these three occur
4. Either A or B but not both

(Note: Provide numerical answers, events were listed as customers buying a-suit, b-shirt, c-tie)

---

My work so far

1. $A^C\cap B^C \cap C^C = (1-A)\cap (1-B) \cap (1-C)$
2. $(A\cap B)\cup (A \cap C)\cup (B \cap A)$
3. $(A \cap (B \cup C)^C) \cup (B \cap (A \cup C)^C) \cup (C \cap (A \cup B)^C)$
4. $(A \cup B) - (A \cap B) = (A)+(B)-(A \cap B) $

---

We were given a few general identities to work with such as $A^C = 1-A$, $(A \cup B) = (A)+(B)-(A \cap B)$ (for overlapping sets), $(A-B)=(A)-(A \cup B)$, and $(A \cap B \cap C) = (A)+(B)+(C)-(A \cup B)- (A \cup C) - (B \cup C) + (A \cup B \cup C)$. What I am really struggling on though is applying my numbers to the statements I have. I believe my logic statements are correct (please correct me if I am wrong!), but I keep stumbling on finding the end value on these.

For example on number 2: $(A\cap B)\cup (A \cap C)\cup (B \cap A)=(0.11) \cup (0.1) \cup (0.14)$ and that I should use the equivalency statement for $(A \cap B \cap C)$ but I get lost on finding what $(A \cup B)$ etc are now.

Comment: You should have $(A \cap B) \cup (B \cap C) \cup (C \cap A)$ for the second problem.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

- For the first part, compute $A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c = (A \cup B \cup C)^c$, compute the probability of the union using inclusion exclusion principle then subtract it from $1$.
- For the second part, apply inclusion exclusion on $(A \cap B) \cup (B \cap C) \cup (A \cap C)$. They are not disjoint.
- For exactly once, you are intested in $A \setminus (B \cup C)$, $B \setminus (A \cup C)$, $C \setminus (A \cup B)$ and note that they are disjoint. Alternatively, consider the probability of at least $1$ subtract away the probability of at least $2$.
- Leaving number $4$ as an exercise. It is similar as part $3$.

Remark: notation like $(0.11) \cup (0.1)$ makes no sense.

Comment: Good to go on 1 now, that made a lot of sense. On 2 this is what I am confused on I am not sure how to apply inclusion exclusion to that statement.

The (rather poor notation) was me trying to state that I understood I have values for those numbers, just not how to use them, but yes it makes no sense mathematically, just wasn't sure how to express myself well.

Comment: let $D, E, F$  be sets, write down inclusion exclusion for them first. After that let $D= A \cap B, E = B \cap C, \ldots$.